# jQuery replace with variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace string with data.replace, its working fine if using hard code or static value. But now i want to replace multiple values with loop but its not working.

My Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
    var r = words[i];
    data = data.replace(/\[(\[qid:{r})\]]/g, words[i]);
}
```

Words contains:

```
Array [ "hid_1", "hid_2", "hid_6", "hid_7" ]
```

and my data is:

```
Site: [[qid:hid_1]]<br>

Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br>

Nimewo kay la: [[qid:hid_6]]<br>

Latitude: [[qid:hid_7]]
```

its an HTML content.

i just need  variable here:

```
for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){

        var r = words[i];
        data = data.replace(/\[(\[qid:hid_1)\]]/g, 'test');
               //data.replace(/\[(\[qid:{r})\]]/g, 'test');

    }
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Expecting: State:  hid_1
Block: hid_2

Comment: Looks like you are using the same regex on each iteration, so each one will be replaced with the first word - is that what's happening?

Comment: actually i have to replace with another one, only for testing i am just replacing with that array valus

Comment: i just want to use variable inside replace..but i can't

Comment: Is your data inside of something like a textarea? Or is that data in an array? Is that data 1 long string?

Comment: HTML data in a variable..

Comment: So it is just a string in a variable then? i.e. `var data = "Site: [[qid:hid_1]]<br> Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br> ..."`

Comment: Yes, there is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var words = [ "hid_1", "hid_2", "hid_6", "hid_7" ];

var data = "Site: [[qid:hid_1]]<br>\
Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br>\
Nimewo kay la: [[qid:hid_6]]<br>\
Latitude: [[qid:hid_7]]";

for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){
        var r = words[i];
        var reg = new RegExp('\\[\\[qid:' + r +'\\]\\]');
        data = data.replace(reg, r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the characters that don't belong. Then, you don't need the other array of replacement strings.

**EDIT**

If your data is one long string, you can do the following:

```js
var data = 'Site: [[qid:hid_1]]<br> Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br> Nimewo kay la: [[qid:hid_6]]<br> Latitude: [[qid:hid_7]]';

data = data.replace(/\[\[qid:(.*?)]](?:<br>)?/g, '$1');

console.log(data);
```

---

Otherwise, if your data is in an array, you could do this:

```js
var strings = [
  'Site: [[qid:hid_1]]<br>',
  'Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br>',
  'Nimewo kay la: [[qid:hid_6]]<br>',
  'Latitude: [[qid:hid_7]]'
];

strings = strings.map(function(string) {
  return string.replace(/\[.*?:([^\]]*).*/, '$1')
});

console.log(strings);
```

Comment: I respect your work.. but did not need this..i just want to replace the searched content with data.replace(/\[(\[qid:hid_1)\]]/g, 'test');

see:  data.replace(/\[(\[qid:hid_1)\]]/g, 'test');   Want:  data.replace(/\[(\[qid:{r})\]]/g, 'test');

here "r" is a variable containing hid_1, hid_2 etc and i just want to replace with test..means in data.replace i just want to place variable {r} so that i can change the string in loop...thanks

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are doing? Is seems fine.

```
 data =["Site: [[qid:hid_1]]",
"Block: [[qid:hid_2]]<br>",
"Nimewo kay la: [[qid:hid_6]]",
"Latitude: [[qid:hid_7]]" ];

var words =  [ "hid_1", "hid_2", "hid_6", "hid_7" ];
for(var i = 0; i<words.length; i++){

    var r = data[i];
    r = r.replace(/\[(\[qid:\w+)\]]/g, words[i]);
  console.log(r);

 }
```